# Simple file reading program with xml rpc using java

Tags: java, apache, xml-rpc

I am a very beginner of Java. Currently I am in need of using Remote Procedure Call (RPC) in Java to read a huge file residing in server. I downloaded apache's xml rpc package. Could anyone please illustrate me with a simple client server program in java using xml rpc package? Thank you.

Comment: if you feel lucky on google while searching for 'xmlrpc java example', you'd go to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml-rpc/xml_rpc_examples.htm which sure looks like a good place to start. You should also lookup xmlrpc basics, and ofcourse java basics, since you mention you are very new to it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XML-RPC-HOWTO/xmlrpc-howto-java.html on Google. Might be of some help to you.